# Nginx configuration for js router

Tags: nginx, url, redirect, router

New project, new problem ;-) I've developed a simple app dealing with URL paths. I'm using `window.location.pathname` for that. Everything is working fine locally, but when deployed on an nginx server, I've got the 404 error when trying to access an URL like `http://monsite.com/passwordreset`. I've tried different config, but no success. So far, my configuration file is:

```
server {

listen 443;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /root/ssl/certificate.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /root/ssl/private.key;

server_name aerokomput.com   www.aerokomput.com;

access_log /var/log/nginx/aerokomput.com.access.log rt_cache; 
error_log /var/log/nginx/aerokomput.com.error.log;

root /var/www/aerokomput.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm;


try_files $uri /index.html;


include common/php.conf;      
include common/locations.conf;
include /var/www/aerokomput.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;
```

}

Any idea to get the URL in the pathname property and make a redirection to the root?

Thanks for your help!

The output of `nginx -T` is:

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 4096;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    ##
    # EasyEngine Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    server_tokens off;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    add_header X-Powered-By "EasyEngine 3.8.1";
    add_header rt-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    # Limit Request
    limit_req_status 403;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

    # Proxy Settings
    # set_real_ip_from  proxy-server-ip;
    # real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHADHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!ECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # Log format Settings
    log_format rt_cache '$remote_addr $upstream_response_time $upstream_cache_status [$time_local] '
    '$http_host "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        text/xml
        text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/blockips.conf:
# Block IP Address
# deny 1.1.1.1;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/fastcgi.conf:
# FastCGI cache settings
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:50m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_503;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 404 1h;
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $http_host;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
fastcgi_keep_conn on;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/force-ssl-aerokomput.com.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.aerokomput.com aerokomput.com;
    return 301 https://aerokomput.com$request_uri;
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf:
# Common upstream settings
upstream php {
# server unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
upstream debug {
# Debug Pool
server 127.0.0.1:9001;
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/22222:
# EasyEngine admin NGINX CONFIGURATION

server {

  listen 22222 default_server ssl http2;

  access_log   /var/log/nginx/22222.access.log rt_cache;
  error_log    /var/log/nginx/22222.error.log;

  ssl_certificate /var/www/22222/cert/22222.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/www/22222/cert/22222.key;

  # Force HTTP to HTTPS
  error_page 497 =200 https://$host:22222$request_uri;

  root /var/www/22222/htdocs;
  index index.php index.htm index.html;

  # Turn on directory listing
  autoindex on;

  # HTTP Authentication on port 22222
  include common/acl.conf;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  # Display menu at location /fpm/status/
  location =  /fpm/status/ {}

  location ~ /fpm/status/(.*) {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME  /status;
    fastcgi_pass $1;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php;
  }

  # ViMbAdmin Rules
  location = /vimbadmin/ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host:22222/vimbadmin/public/;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|gif|png)$ {
    root /var/www/22222/htdocs/;
  }

  location ~* /vimbadmin/public/(.*)/(.*) {
    root /var/www/22222/htdocs/vimbadmin/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/  /vimbadmin/public/index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~* /vimbadmin/public/(.*) {
    root /var/www/22222/htdocs/vimbadmin/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/  /vimbadmin/public/index.php?$args;
  }

}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/common/acl.conf:
# EasyEngine (ee) protect locations using
# HTTP authentication || IP address
satisfy any;
auth_basic "Restricted Area";
auth_basic_user_file htpasswd-ee;
# Allowed IP Address List
allow 127.0.0.1;
deny all;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME      $request_filename;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# To fix CGI application vulnerability - https://httpoxy.org
fastcgi_param   HTTP_PROXY      "";

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/acpe-cas.fr:

server {


    server_name acpe-cas.fr   www.acpe-cas.fr;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/acpe-cas.fr.access.log ; 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/acpe-cas.fr.error.log;


    root /var/www/acpe-cas.fr;



    index  index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }



    include common/locations.conf;
    include /var/www/acpe-cas.fr/conf/nginx/*.conf;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/common/locations.conf:
# NGINX CONFIGURATION FOR COMMON LOCATION
# DO NOT MODIFY, ALL CHANGES LOST AFTER UPDATE EasyEngine (ee)
# Basic locations files
location = /favicon.ico {
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
  expires max;
}
location = /robots.txt {
  # Some WordPress plugin gererate robots.txt file
  # Refer #340 issue
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
}
# Cache static files
location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|swf)$ {
  add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
  expires max;
}
# Security settings for better privacy
# Deny hidden files
location ~ /\.well-known {
  allow all;
}
location ~ /\. {
  deny all;
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
}
# Deny backup extensions & log files
location ~* ^.+\.(bak|log|old|orig|original|php#|php~|php_bak|save|swo|swp|sql)$ {
  deny all;
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
}
# Return 403 forbidden for readme.(txt|html) or license.(txt|html) or example.(txt|html)
if ($uri ~* "^.+(readme|license|example)\.(txt|html)$") {
  return 403;
}
# Status pages
location = /nginx_status {
  stub_status on;
  access_log off;
  include common/acl.conf;
}
location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass php;
  include common/acl.conf;
}
# EasyEngine (ee) utilities
# phpMyAdmin settings
location = /pma {
  return 301 https://$host:22222/db/pma;
}
location = /phpMyAdmin {
  return 301 https://$host:22222/db/pma;
}
location = /phpmyadmin {
  return 301 https://$host:22222/db/pma;
}
# Adminer settings
location = /adminer {
  return 301 https://$host:22222/db/adminer;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/aerokomput.com:
server {

    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /root/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/ssl/private.key;

    server_name aerokomput.com   www.aerokomput.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/aerokomput.com.access.log rt_cache; 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/aerokomput.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/aerokomput.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    try_files $uri /index.html;


    include common/php.conf;      
    include common/locations.conf;
    include /var/www/aerokomput.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/common/php.conf:
# PHP NGINX CONFIGURATION
# DO NOT MODIFY, ALL CHANGES LOST AFTER UPDATE EasyEngine (ee)
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass php;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    #
    # ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # don’t use SSLv3 ref: POODLE
    # ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    # ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Well the includes should also be shown. please can you post the output of `nginx -T` (capital T)

Comment: The server block for `aerokomput.com` includes `php.conf` which sends users to `index.php` which is presumably not found on this server. Try removing the include.

Comment: That solved the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thanks to Richard Smith:

> The server block for aerokomput.com includes php.conf which sends users to index.php which is presumably not found on this server. Try removing the include.